# The Primal and Dual attack security estimates in Kyber round 3 specification

Tags: lattice-crypto, attack, kyber

In Kyber round 3 specification, the table 4 gave the security estimates of Primal and Dual attack with respect to Kyber 512, 768 and 1024 (see the figure below). However, using the python script given in the paper (see the [github](https://github.com/pq-crystals/security-estimates), run *Kyber.py*), it seems that I cannot reproduce the same result (however the numbers are very closed). I cannot figure out the reason, need help.

The result I get by this script is:

```
Kyber512 (light):
--------------------
security:
Primal attacks uses block-size 406 and 486 samples; dim d=999
Primal & 486 & 406 & 118 & 107 & 84
Dual attacks uses block-size 403 and 512 samples; dim d=1024
shortest vector used has length l=3294.02, q=3329, `l<q'= 1
log2(epsilon) = -41.82, log2 nvector per run 83.63
Dual & 512 & 403 & 117 & 106 & 83 
params:  {'n': 256, 'm': 2, 'ks': 3, 'ke': 3, 'ke_ct': 2, 'q': 3329, 'rqk': 4096, 'rqc': 1024, 'rq2': 16}
com costs:  (800.0, 768.0)
failure: 0.0 = 2^-139.1

Kyber768 (recommended):
--------------------
security:
Primal attacks uses block-size 626 and 650 samples; dim d=1419
Primal & 650 & 626 & 183 & 166 & 129
Dual attacks uses block-size 620 and 650 samples; dim d=1418
shortest vector used has length l=5003.21, q=3329, `l<q'= 0
log2(epsilon) = -64.32, log2 nvector per run 128.66
Dual & 650 & 620 & 181 & 164 & 128 
params:  {'n': 256, 'm': 3, 'ks': 2, 'ke': 2, 'ke_ct': 2, 'q': 3329, 'rqk': 4096, 'rqc': 1024, 'rq2': 16}
com costs:  (1184.0, 1088.0)
failure: 0.0 = 2^-165.2

Kyber1024 (paranoid):
--------------------
security:
Primal attacks uses block-size 878 and 860 samples; dim d=1885
Primal & 860 & 878 & 256 & 232 & 182
Dual attacks uses block-size 868 and 838 samples; dim d=1862
shortest vector used has length l=5920.11, q=3329, `l<q'= 0
log2(epsilon) = -90.06, log2 nvector per run 180.13
Dual & 838 & 868 & 253 & 230 & 180 
params:  {'n': 256, 'm': 4, 'ks': 2, 'ke': 2, 'ke_ct': 2, 'q': 3329, 'rqk': 4096, 'rqc': 2048, 'rq2': 32}
com costs:  (1568.0, 1568.0)
failure: 0.0 = 2^-175.2
```

[image]